# Excel VBA does not delete rows in some cases

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to delete visible rows in excel (after filtering for values greater than 30). The issue that I'm facing is that the code works fine and deletes the rows when the values (greater than 30) are in sequence, but it does not delete the rows and it gives an error when the values are not in sequence. What am I doing wrong?

```
'With rng
     .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">30"
     .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
     .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">0"
End With '
```

I get the error: `Delete method of Range class failed`

This is what the data that I'm trying to remove looks like:

[image]

How range is set:

```
Dim rng As Range

LastRow = btsvoice.Range("M" & btsvoice.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = btsvoice.Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
```

Below is the entire module code:

```
Sub Delete_Row_Final()

    Dim voice As Workbook
    Dim data As Workbook
    Dim btsvoice As Worksheet
    Dim nodebvoice As Worksheet
    Dim btsdata As Worksheet
    Dim enodebdata As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MyRange As Range

    Set voice = Workbooks("Voice_Files.xlsx")
    Set btsvoice = voice.Sheets("2G Voice")
    Set nodebvoice = voice.Sheets("3G Voice")

    Set data = Workbooks("Data_Files.xlsx")
    Set btsdata = data.Sheets("2G Data")
    Set enodebdata = data.Sheets("4G Data")

    Application.Calculate
    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        DoEvents
    End If

    ' -------------------  2G Voice ------------------------
    'filter and delete all but header row which is in row 3
LastRow = btsvoice.Range("M" & btsvoice.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = btsvoice.Range("M1:M" & LastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
         .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">30"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">0"
    End With

    ' -------------------  3G Voice ------------------------
    'filter and delete all but header row which is in row 3
    LastRow = nodebvoice.Range("K" & nodebvoice.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = nodebvoice.Range("K2:K" & LastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
         .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">30"
         .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
         .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">0"
    End With

    voice.Save

        ' -------------------  2G Data ------------------------
    'filter and delete all but header row which is in row 3
    LastRow = btsdata.Range("L" & btsdata.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = btsdata.Range("L2:L" & LastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
         .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">30"
         .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
         .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">0"
    End With

            ' -------------------  4G Data ------------------------
    'filter and delete all but header row which is in row 3
    LastRow = enodebdata.Range("M" & enodebdata.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = enodebdata.Range("M2:M" & LastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
         .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">30"
         .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
         .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">0"
    End With

    data.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you meant to use: `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`. Besides that, you should include a screenshot of how your data looks like when filtered, and which error you get on which line.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for the suggestion. Whats odd is that it used to work fine. It just randomly started giving me the error today. Do you have any guesses as to what may be causing the issue?

Comment: Well, I can't think of what has cause the error in the first place since I reproduced it just once, while on a second run it worked fine. Can you include how you get `rng`.

Comment: try to move delete entire after filter

Comment: As @JvdV pointed, I think your issue might be how you set your `rng` variable. If you can provide that bit of code, it would help

Comment: @JvdV I've updated my question with code for range.

Comment: @Zac I've updated my question with code for range.

Comment: @KubaDo I'me trying to delete the rows based on the filtered value. I don't think that would work

Comment: Some discrepancy between the range you set and the filter you apply there. While range only happens to be column H, you cannot reference field 13 (it doesn't exist). Surely this was unintentional? You mentioned how this stopped working/throwing an error out of the blue. In case this is a mishap on your end, you will have to use `Set rng = btsvoice.Range("H2:M" & LastRow)` and filter like: `.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">30"` to filter column M

Comment: @aab i ment to switch places beetween DeleteEntire and.Filter Criteria >0, i was wondering if order does impact

Comment: @JvdV I copied the range from a different module for a different workbook by mistake. I've rectified my question.

Comment: @KubaDo I would not be able to delete the rows that I wnated to delete if I do it that way, as that would put the filter back to >0 before it deleting all rows with values >30

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your current question and explaination, I think there must have slipped an extra `3` into your code:

If you set range:

```
LastRow = btsvoice.Range("M" & btsvoice.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = btsvoice.Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
```

You can't index to `Field:=13` as it's simply not present in a 1-column range. Use `Field:=1` instead.

However, some other pointers to make is that since you have headers, it could be even better to use `Offset`, making your code looking like:

```
Dim rng As Range

LastRow = btsvoice.Range("M" & btsvoice.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = btsvoice.Range("M1:M" & LastRow)

With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">30"
    .Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
End With
```

---

One other thing I can imagine: The described error will also be thrown when `AutoFilter` is already applied on one single column, and you want to `AutoFilter` another single column. That means that you have two options:

- Remove `AutoFilter` before you apply another filter
- Apply the filter to a full range instead of single columns

For the first option you could try:

```
With Sheet1
    If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End with
```

For the second option you need to set your range to be column A:M (or even further)

```
Set rng = btsvoice.Range("A2:M" & LastRow)
```

Comment: `Field:=1` filters column `A` for me, whilst `Field:=13` filters column `M` as intended. The error occurs at the line`.Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`. I've added `offset `to the rest of my code. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my question with the full module code. Maybe that might help

Comment: @aab, that behavior tells me that there still is another `AutoFilter` applied to the range `A:A`. Notice that your code will use that same `AutoFilter` and tries to filter on field 13 which is impossible since you have not set rng to be multiple columns. I have updated my answer accordingly.